# why is the enabled flag false for some users?

Tags: powershell

I tried Get-LocalUser on powershell to see a list of users I observed few users have enabled as "True" and few as "False". Why?

[image]

Comment: It's a good question, but one that is neither related to PowerShell (which is just the messenger here) nor to programming, so I suggest asking your question on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 2):

Well these are accounts for users of certain type, and have particular usages. Take the `Administrator`, for example. It is disabled by default because it has higher level privileges and can potentially perform disastrous operations if not used with caution. The enabled ones, are usually the ones that are created by the user of the computer (the ones shown in the login screen).